# Tmux ctrl+v conflicts with Vim's block selection

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I'm using tmux 2.1 and as I'm big fan of vim's block selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) I would like to stop using it inside **tmux** to paste, how can I configure that?.

I've tried `unbind C-v` on my `~/.tmux.conf` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem of your terminal emulator. I don't see a `C-v` binding in vanilla `tmux`. You can verify if it's indeed `tmux` to blame by listing all the key bindings via `tmux list-keys` command.

You can also test it with

```
bind-key  C-v send-key C-v
```